# When is sys.stdin None in Python?

Tags: python, iis, cgi, flask, python-3.3

I'm trying to run Flask as a simple CGI app through IIS.

I have the following code:

```
from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'Woo woo!'

CGIHandler().run(app)
```

I'm runing Python 3.3 on Windows. I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", 
line 509, in __init__(self, sys.stdin.buffer, sys.stdout.buffer, sys.stderr, )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'buffer' ".
```

I added some logging code, and it turns out that `sys.stdin` is `None`.

Python is added to IIS as a CGI Handler as follows:

```
Request path: *.py
Executable: C:\Windows\py.exe -3 %s %s
```

So, why is sys.stdin None, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

It looks like sys.stdin is None because the [file descriptor is invalid](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c9545c2386c4/Python/pythonrun.c#l1090).

Comment: While migrating an existing website with multiple Python CGI scripts from Apache to IIS, I noticed that stdin is None for the POST requests without any Form Data provided

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting.  You've answered half your own question.  The other half ("how do I fix it") is easy enough, just open some suitable thing (`os.devnull` is the obvious one) and set sys.stdin to point there.  You'll need to do sys.stdout and sys.stderr as well, presumably, so something like this:

```
import os, sys
for _name in ('stdin', 'stdout', 'stderr'):
    if getattr(sys, _name) is None:
        setattr(sys, _name, open(os.devnull, 'r' if _name == 'stdin' else 'w'))
del _name # clean up this module's name space a little (optional)
from wsgiref.handlers ...
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This ended out being half my solution - the other half was using `IISCGIHandler()`, because apparently IIS has some problems. Also, I just ended out replacing `stdin` with `os.devnull` and life was peachy.

Comment: @WayneWerner, could you please advise what is `IISCGIHandler()`? Is that function/class you created? Could you please share it?

Comment: @SergeyNudnov a quick Google search for `python iiscgihandler` turned up https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.handlers.IISCGIHandler