# Python executable not working if console is hidden, using Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, executable, moviepy

I have a Python 3.8.0 program that downloads videos from YouTube, extracts their audio and creates an mp3, all this with a Tkinter interface. The program works perfect from VScode. I made it into an executable with the command 'pyinstaller --onefile code.py'; the GUI and the console appear, and it works.

Now if I add '-w' to create an executable with no console, just GUI, the program fails.
The exception is: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write' and happenns in the next lines:

```
absolute_route = os.path.abspath(routemp4)
video = VideoFileClip(absolute_route)
routemp3 = absolute_route[:len(absolute_route)-4] + ".mp3"
video.audio.write_audiofile(routemp3)
```

'
routemp4 is the path of an mp4 file taken with 'youtubeObject.default_filename', is valid and has audio (again, the exact same code works with the console open).

I figured it might be the paths, as if the console is closed the GUI program might have troubles, but I added absolute paths and nothing changed.

The code works just fine if the console is open but fails if it is just the GUI.
There is a similar stackoverflow question but it was solved since the guy´s video had no audio, which is not my case. My problem lays within the GUI and console.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Python is started without a console, `sys.stdout` will be set to `None`. This is mentioned in the [docs for the sys module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__).

Presumably something is calling `sys.stdout.write`, which would cause the error you're seeing.

As mentioned in [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49757760/896841), if you can change the code to call `print` instead of `sys.stdout.write`, then this will be handled for you (i.e. nothing will be printed and no error will be raised).

If you can't change whatever code is calling `sys.stdout.write`, then, as suggested in [an answer to a different related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17459258/896841), you could set `sys.stdout` (at the start of your program) to a file object that does nothing:

```py
import sys, os
if sys.stdout is None:
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, "w")
```

That should get rid of the error. If not, try doing the same for `sys.stderr` in addition to `sys.stdout`, in case something is trying to write to the standard error stream.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved the problem; Asking on stackoverflow was my last resort and I tought no one would answer but you proved me wrong, again, thank you.